# Laravel Form::text styling with default value

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried the following code:

```
{{ Form::text('username', 'Usuario', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

But it fails, it throws this error:

```
ErrorException
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /mydir/app/views/sessions/create.blade.php)

/mydir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
     * Escape HTML entities in a string.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    function e($value)
    {
        return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you comment out that form field? I don't think it's introduced with that line.

Comment: @hannesvdvreken What do you mean?

Comment: Try commenting out that one line. Maybe it is introduced in another `Form::text` call.

Comment: @hannesvdvreken Why would I like to do that? I want the text field to show

Comment: @zyngawow you'd do that for debug purposes so we would know if that line is really the culprit.

Comment: Because clearly another `Form::text` call is wrong. You just want to be sure the exception is **not** caused by `Form::text('username', ...`

Comment: Ok I think it was that. I had a default text for my password field. Can't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation api says:

```
/**
 * Create a text input field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
 public function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
 {
     return $this->input('text', $name, $value, $options);
 }
```

It means that:

```
// ...is correct
Form::text(   'username', 'Usuario', array('class' => 'form-control')   )
```

So that line is not the culprit. You'd have to check the stack trace for what line it is giving the error at.

---

**Update**

I saw you talking about a password field on the comments. The proper way of using the password field is:

```
public function password($name, $options = array())
{
    return $this->input('password', $name, '', $options);
}
```

You asked:

> Ok I think it was that. I had a default text for my password field.
>   Can't I?

The answer is

> NO, you cannot. but you can try `Form::input`.

```
/**
 * Create a form input field.
 *
 * @param  string  $type
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
 public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = array()) {
```

So do it like: (*warning untested code*)

```
Form::input('password', 'passwordfield', 'defaultvalue', array('class' => 'myclass'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to fill in a default. Maybe you want to use a `placeholder`. Try:

```
{{ Form::text('username', null, array(
    'class' => 'form-control', 
    'placeholder' => 'Usuario',
  )) 
}}
```